# Is it ok to edit directly .aspx pages on a SharePoint site?

Tags: web-services, html-editor

Let's suppose I want to have a "clean" html page with just some javascript scripts using jQuery, interacting with SharePoint via web services.
 In order to do this, I create a new page (say *test.aspx*) on a page library, and edit this page by opening it directly from a text editor in my PC, and then wipe everything and start from scratch editing the html of this page. I don't even have any server code on the page, but I keep the aspx extension because html uploads are forbidden in my farm.
**What could possibly go wrong?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing would go wrong. Your edited aspx page would be rendered as a normal web page (depending on what html code you inserted) but will not inherit the Master Page features (design and layout).

Answer (score 2):

Wiping everything is not a good idea - as @Zakir HC mentioned, you loose the MasterPage Features.
That could increase the efforts to migrate and maintain the solution.

Additionally: If you modify the page like that the page will be stored in the database and could increase the load (possible but unlikely).

Answer (score 1):

It would be essentially like uploading a html file. No master page features or SharePoint banner. The only possible errors that I could envision is SharePoint not recognising it as a valid page.

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to create a standard .aspx page and add a Content Editor Webpart to it, pointed to a text file/javascript file. Store that in Site Assets or somewhere, then you can do all your code in that which will define what you see on your page. I do a lot of 'one page' apps like this using JQuery, SPServices, other JQuery plugins, where I have to mix a bunch of different lists and css styles.